# JIRA to BigQuery API

Tags: api, google-bigquery, jira

I am looking for an API which allows me to transer data from Jira to Google Bigquery. My goal is to get the same data as the one within time report. It is important to get the columns of log work started and time spent(h) do you know any good API for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Jira REST API to retrieve data from Jira and then use the BigQuery API to load the data into BigQuery.